# Enable youtube in pakistan

Tags: wordpress, proxy, youtube

i have a WordPress site and i want to run youtube videos in my site but in my Pakistan youtube is blocked is any option in wordpress to play youtube videos in my site?

Comment: wordpress is a CMS, why would there be an option in it to play youtube videos? What you need is a proxy.

Comment: because i upload most of my videos on youtube and embed in my website but in pakistan youtube is blocked and my site is down please tell me is any solution to run videos on my website

Comment: sir Wajahat can you help me?

Comment: No I can't, I think what you are asking is possible through a proxy but I don't know exactly how it will be implemented.

Answer (score 2):

if Pakistan ISP's are blocking youtube, there's not much you can do. There are probably ways to unblock it, like using an intermediate server (on which youtube isn't blocked) and streaming it back to the client that is trying to watch the video, but that would probably be considered illegal.

If you still want to make your video's available to your users, I think your best solution would be to upload your video to some other kind of social media (facebook?) that isn't blocked and share them through an embedded link. Or upload your video's to your webserver and use the HTML5 video tag to make your video's viewable on your website.

Comment: some days earlier a website http://ishowtube.com/ that paly directly youtube videos, but now these days it is closed and there is another website tune.pk its also play youtube videos, how they can do theis??

Comment: @user1596202 I dont see any **youtube** video's on tune.pk. I think they upload video's to their own webserver, and make it viewable with their own video player (I am guessing the player is custom because it shows custom buttons on the player like >tune). So it resembles the solution in my given answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can Embed, Watch Youtube Videos or Download :)

http://playit.pk/

PlayIt.pk brings multitude of features under one umbrella making video discovery, sharing and downloading easier than ever.